# How to create the duplicate widget?

Tags: python, python-3.x, widget, kivy

I'm trying create new TabbedPanelItem with properties already created widget. But i'm getting new empty widget or replace exist.

.py

```
    class MainScreen(Screen):
        def add(self, tabbed_item):
            new_tabbed_item = TabbedPanelItem()
            new_tabbed_item.properties = copy(tabbed_item)
            new_tabbed_item.text = "2"
            self.ids.tab_panel.add_widget(new_tabbed_item)
```

.kv

```
    <MainScreen>:
        AnchorLayout:
            canvas.before:
                ...     
            TabbedPanel:
                id: tab_panel
                ...

                TabbedPanelItem:
                    Button:
                        on_press: root.add(tab_item)


                TabbedPanelItem:
                    id: tab_item
                    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

When I try to run you're code nothing pops up. You don't have enough code to test. I'm not sure what your goal is, but if you want to have a TabbedPanelItem with stuff already created without having to reproduce the same code (if that's your goal), try using @. An example: `MyTabbedPanel@TabbedPanelItem:`. Then you can add everything you want it to do, and reuse it instead of retyping out the code everytime.

Comment: Did this help at all?